# Binance how get account information?

Tags: account, binance, uid, info

I want to get some unique account information like email or user id from binance api using any way, I have api key and secret.

Comment: Binance API doesn't provide unique user information such as e-mail and ID, most likely for security reasons... What is your incentive for getting the user info? Maybe there's another way to achieve the same goal.

Comment: Duplicate, the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71380857/binance-api-how-to-get-binance-user-id-using-api